# How to create a class without any constructor just like MessageBox class

Tags: c#, winforms, class

How can i create a class with zero constructor, just like MessageBox class which has no constructor.
I can not make this class static, beacause a public static method is declared in it, and that method makes object of this class.
in C# 3.5

i want to make this class just like System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox class, 
in which there is no constructor and 
when we create object of this class error occurres :

this class has no constructor

where as a class with a private constructor when object creates error occurrs -

the constructor is not accessible due to its protection level.

Comment: yes a constuctor declared with zero args

Comment: i want to make this class just like System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox class, in which there is no constructor and when we create object of this class error occurres this class has no constructor where as a class witch a private constructor when declares error occurrs - the constructor is not accessible due to its protection level

Comment: Re your edit: the only way to create a class without **any** constructor is to make it static. In c# a non-static class *always* has a constructor of some kind (even abstract classes have a protected constructor by default). The issue of the message "no constructors" vs "not accessible do to its protection level" sounds simply like the difference between using something in the same assembly, vs using something in a referenced assembly.

Comment: Confirmed; I created two simple classes with private constructors - one in the current assembly, and one in a referenced assembly. The first gives the "protection level" message; the second gives the "no constructors defined" message.

Comment: Marc Gravell : thanks Mr. Marc i m going to try this may be this is the answer that i am looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to create a class without a constructor is to use `static class`.

However, it seem you want to be able to create instances of this class from inside the class itself, which is not possible with a static class. For that, you should give the class a private constructor:

```
class Foo
{
    private Foo() { }

    public static Foo Create()
    {
        return new Foo(); // Only members of Foo can directly invoke the constructor.
    }
}
```

If a method outside of Foo in the same assembly tries to instantiate Foo, the message given will be that the constructor is not accessible due to its protection level. If you try to access it from another assembly, it will give the message that Foo has no constructors.

Comment: i cant make this static or abstract

Comment: In that case, make the constructor private. I have updated the answer accordingly

Comment: @Sven for clarity; `MessageBox` is implemented as a non-static class with all-static methods, and a private constructor; however, if `static class` had been available when it was written (1.x), I fully expect it would have been implemented as a static class. If you "can't make this static or abstract", then it sounds like you don't have the same scenario as `MessageBox`, as they *could* have made `MessageBox` a static class.

Comment: @MarcGravell : MessageBox has no constructor in it, 
the clarification is in my question.

Comment: @Marc: Yes, you're right of course. Pesky C# 1.0... I can barely remember what I had for dinner last week, let alone the rules of a language 7 years out of date. :P

Comment: @Haider: As Marc said, MessageBox *does* have a constructor, but it's private.

Comment: @HaiderAli No, you are mistaken. It **does** have a constructor - I'm looking at the IL. It has a `private MessageBox() {}`. I know *because I'm looking at it*. I have clarified the compiler messages in a comment on the question.

Comment: Marc Gravell : thanks Mr. Marc i m going to try this may be this is the answer that i am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The methods on `MessageBox` are *static*; you can do that with the `static` modifier:

```
public static class Foo {
    public static void Bar() {...}
}
```

then:

```
Foo.Bar();
```

In earlier versions of c# (before `static` was allowed on classes) you had to cheat:

```
public class Foo {
    private Foo() {} // hide the constructor
    public static void Bar() {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it static class with no constructor or make it an Abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

Make a static class, or make a class with a private constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can add public STATIC methods into your class and you would acheve the same as in messagebox. 
Remember that static methods cannot access non static properties or methods in the same class.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Consider usage of Creational patterns, described in GOF (["Gang Of Four"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns#Creational_patterns))

There are the following ways:

1) If you want to have only one instance of object to be created, use [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

There is a good example of thread-safe singleton on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)

> In this strategy, the instance is created the first time any member of
>   the class is referenced

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
   private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

   private Singleton(){}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         return instance; 
      }
   }
}
```

2) If you don't want to specify the exact class to create, use [Factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Here is an extract from an article on C#-Corner [Factory method Design pattern using C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/kalisk/factory-method-design-pattern-using-C-Sharp/)

```
abstract class Factory 
    {
        public abstract Product GetProduct(); //Factory Method Declaration
    }

class concreteFactoryforProcuct1 : Factory
    {
        public override Product GetProduct() //Factory Method Implementation
            {
                return new Product1();
            }
    }
```

3) If there is a group of objects to be created this way, use [Abstract factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)

Here are extracts from an article on codeproject: [Understanding and implementing abstract factory pattern in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328373/Understanding-and-Implementing-Abstract-Factory-Pa)

Creating the Abstract Factory

```
interface IPhoneFactory //'I' stands for interface no relation with Iphone
{
    ISmart GetSmart();
    IDumb GetDumb();
}
```

Creating the Concrete Factories

```
class SamsungFactory : IPhoneFactory
{
    public ISmart GetSmart()
    {
        return new GalaxyS2();
    }

    public IDumb GetDumb()
    {
        return new Primo();
    }
}
...
```

Creating the Client

```
enum MANUFACTURERS
{
    SAMSUNG,
    HTC,
    NOKIA
}
class PhoneTypeChecker
{
    IPhoneFactory factory;
    ...
    public PhoneTypeChecker(MANUFACTURERS m)
    {
        m_manufacturer= m;
    }

    public void CheckProducts()
    {
        switch (m_manufacturer)
        {
            case MANUFACTURERS.SAMSUNG:
                factory = new SamsungFactory();
                break;
            case MANUFACTURERS.HTC:
                factory = new HTCFactory();
                break;
            case MANUFACTURERS.NOKIA:
                factory = new NokiaFactory();
                break;
        }
        ...
        factory.GetSmart();
        factory.GetDumb();
        ...
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PhoneTypeChecker checker = new PhoneTypeChecker(MANUFACTURERS.SAMSUNG);
    checker.CheckProducts();

    ...
}
```

4) Use you common sense to develop your own design that would satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of it is not allowing user it instantiate new instances of the class  you could make 
all constructors less visible then public .

For example - protected.